# apiRTC Voice call also show video of call receiver

Tags: jquery, video-streaming, webrtc, audio-streaming

I have used apiRTC js to integrate video and voice call in my project.
Video call works perfect. But I am facing issue in voice call. 
During voice call when the recipient user accepts the incoming call request, his video is also shown to call sender. i.e. video stream is also passed along with audio stream to remote container.

Below is my code to place a call:

```
var contact = connectedSession.getOrCreateContact($("#pntNum").val());
var call = contact.call(null, {audioOnly: true});
if (call !== null) {
    if (call.getContact().userData.audioDevicePresent == "true") {
            setCallListeners(call);
            addHangupButton(call.getId());
            hideMuteButtons();
        } 
    } else {
        console.warn('Please make sure that your machine has audio device installed.');
    }
} else {
    console.warn("Cannot establish call");
}
```

If anyone knows how to solve this issue then please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of {audioOnly: true}, use {mediaTypeForOutgoingCall : 'AUDIO'}, for caller.

For callee, try to set the following answerOptions {mediaTypeForIncomingCall : AUDIO} in your accept() method :

```
var answerOptions = {
    mediaTypeForIncomingCall : 'AUDIO'
};
invitation.accept(null, answerOptions)
    .then(function (call) {
        setCallListeners(call);
        addHangupButton(call.getId());
    });
```